# Issue deploying Hello World Sinatra app on Heroku.

Tags: git, deployment, heroku

Here's the code:

```
# helloworld.rb

require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
'Hello world! Welcome to the root!'
end
```

and when I deploy to Heroku I get this in my logs:

```
2012-02-03T23:18:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-02-03T23:18:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-02-03T23:18:47+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-02-03T23:18:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 17403 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]: <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- helloworld (LoadError)
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-02-03T23:18:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-02-03T23:18:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-02-03T23:18:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-02-03T23:18:57+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET alterra.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-02-03T23:18:57+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 129.89.10.150 - - [03/Feb/2012:23:18:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.46 Safari/535.11" alterra.heroku.com
```

I'm completely new to this, so I assume I'm doing something wrong or forgot to include something. I just get the H10 app crashed error and the Application Error page.

Comment: A bit more detail about what you expect, what you've tried etc can be helpful to potential answerers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config.ru` you need to change

```
require 'helloworld'
```

to

```
require './helloworld'
```

This is a change that was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2, where the current directory is no longer on the load path. If this is working for you on your local machine, then you could be using Ruby 1.8.7. If this is the case then it would be worth looking into upgrading to 1.9.2.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also didn't have a Gemfile. I'm running 1.9.2 on a newer model MacBook Pro. When I run Sinatra on my machine it doesn't seem to care if I don't have a Gemfile or config.ru file. A lot of this is new to me. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, ok, so you're running locally with `ruby helloworld.rb`. If you want to test your `config.ru` locally you can simply type `rackup`, or if you have Thin installed, `thin start`, which is what you'll probably be using on Heroku.